# QFileSystemModel setNameFilter format for files without extension

Tags: qt, qfilesystemmodel

Is there any way to display all files without extension by using setNameFilters? I know how to do it with files with multiple extensions (like the .txt in the example below), but I don't know how to do it to detect files with no extension, rather than with regexp, but then I would need something like this (which I want to avoid if I can do it directly with setNameFilters):

```
QSortFilterProxyModel* filter = new QSortFilterProxyModel(model);
filter->setFilterRegExp(QRegExp("^([^.]+)$", Qt::CaseInsensitive));
```

This is the sample code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    Filemodel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    Filemodel->setFilter( QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Files );

    QStringList filters;
    filters << "*.txt";

    Filemodel.setNameFilters(filters);
    Filemodel.setNameFilterDisables(false);

    ui->Filtered_tbView->setModel( Filemodel );
}
```

So basically on setNameFilters I want to add a condition to not consider files with a dot on it (I know how to do it when I want the files to include a specific string - which can be the extension-, but not when I want to NOT include a specific string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. The only way to do that would be with a proxy model. You can't even do that in `QDir::setNameFilters()`, either. Explanation follows...

Did you try to list your directory files within `cmd.exe`? you may use something like:

```
dir *.
```

that would do the trick, right? And now open Powershell instead, and try to do the same :-) It doesn't work! Of course, in powershell `dir` is an alias for `Get-ChildItem`, and there is another way to express that:

```
Get-ChildItem -Exclude *.*
```

And you can do something similar in you Linux terminal:

```
ls -I '*.*'
```

But there is nothing similar in Qt classes `QDir` nor `QFileSystemModel`. You would need an `excludeNameFilter()` method (that would be a nice addition to Qt, by the way!).

The explanation is that Qt, powershell and ls use the same [globbing syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) and there is no way to express on it  a positive filter including only files without dots, like you do in the regular expression.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up creating a QSortFilterProxyModel and it works like a charm (I agree it would be nice to be able to filter by exclusion or by using a regexp without having to create a proxy model.